# Unable to run BeautifulSoup in Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, virtualenv

I've installed BeatifulSoup4 in my virtual environment as shown below.  I'm able to import and use it normally inside my virtual environment interpreter; however, the interpreter couldn't find BeatifulSoup when I run the script directly.  I haven't installed BeatifulSoup in my native environment.  How do I force my script to run in a virtual environment where BeatifulSoup is installed?

```
(virtual) $ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)
bs4 (0.0.1)
certifi (2017.11.5)
cffi (1.9.1)
chardet (3.0.4)
colored (1.3.4)
cryptography (1.6)
et-xmlfile (1.0.1)
idna (2.6)
jdcal (1.3)
numpy (1.13.1)
openpyxl (2.4.8)
pandas (0.20.3)
paramiko (2.0.2)
pip (9.0.1)
progressbar2 (3.34.2)
psycopg2 (2.6.2)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.17)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
python-utils (2.2.0)
pytz (2017.2)
readline (6.2.4.1)
requests (2.18.4)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
terminaltables (3.1.0)
urllib3 (1.22)
wheel (0.29.0)
xlrd (1.1.0)
(virtual) $

(virtual) $ python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Here's a snippet of my "webscraping.py" code in case it helps.

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

from requests import get

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
response = get (url)
print ('Result from response:')
print (response.text [:500])

html = BeautifulSoup (response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Attempting to run in a virtual environment but got a TypeError.

```
(virtual) $ python webscraping.py 
Result from response:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=342792525, app-argument=imdb:///?src=mdot">
            <script type="text/javascript">var ue_t0=window.ue_t0||+new Date();</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var ue_mid = "A1EVAM02EL8SFB"; 
                var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraping.py", line 88, in <module>
    main ()
  File "webscraping.py", line 39, in main
    html = BeautifulSoup (response.text, 'html.parser')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Testing the same line of code in my virtual environment interpreter show no error and work as expected.

```
(virtual) $ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 22 2016, 19:03:10) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from requests import get
>>> 
>>> url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
>>> response = get (url)
>>> print (response.text [:500])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=342792525, app-argument=imdb:///?src=mdot">
            <script type="text/javascript">var ue_t0=window.ue_t0||+new Date();</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var ue_mid = "A1EVAM02EL8SFB"; 
                var
>>> 
>>> html = BeautifulSoup (response.text, 'html.parser')
>>> html

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="app-id=342792525, app-argument=imdb:///?src=mdot" name="apple-itunes-app"/>
<script type="text/javascript">var ue_t0=window.ue_t0||+new Date();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported `bs4` as a module `BeautifulSoup`, not a surprize you got `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Module `BeautifulSoup` is not callable.

You have to access something in the module (class `BeautifulSoup` in your case). There're 2 ways to do that: either access class `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup` or import it directly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that statement.  In case it's not obvious to others, I had "import bs4 as BeautifuSoup" in my script and "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" in my interpreter.  Changing to what suggested in the answer works!